# Port Flash to iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash

How hard would it be to port a flash game to the iPhone. Obviously Flash CS5 is no longer an options, I still would like to know if there's anything that can be reused? or do I have to write everything from scratch (Is Obj-C that different than ActionScript?) Is there any other shortcuts?
Also, if anyone has done this before please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the same thing.  I am using [Cocos2d for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  This is a pretty good 2d game engine.  Actually, two apps created with it are in the current top 25.  You are going to have to get down and dirty in Objective-C though.  Objective-C is different from ActionScript but if you are use to object oriented programming you should be able to make the switch.  Programming a Flash game is different than typical game programming done in Objective-C/C/C++.  So, if you are familiar with how to do things in the Objective-C/C/C++ game programming world (render loop, capturing inputs, etc), you'll really be ok.  If not, you'll have to get use to not having the Flash timeline, dealing with frames, etc.  Good luck!  You can do it!

Answer (score 2):

Flash is a very different platform, not only is the language change going to be an issue you're going to be going from Flash's renderer to presumably your own using OpenGL:ES.

Although another method may be to port your app to JavaScript. Both ActionScript and JavaScript are  EMCAScript dialects, so very similar in that area, the APIs will be completely different though.

http://paulirish.com/work/gordon/demos/ interesting and slightly related, this is a implementation of Flash in JavaScript.

Note the new Apple T.O.S may affect you, but as far as I'm aware it's still a beta and I'm not Apple or a lawyer so I won't try and decipher it for you.

Answer (score 0):

read the statements from apple, no its not possible.

Comment: I know that. I'm asking how to convert the code manually. wanted to see if there's any tips

Answer (score 0):

For my game Hudriks I used flash to build levels and some animations. For this an animation engine has been developed that supports motion tween, and then wrote JSFL scripts that goes through Flash objects and export to a format that can be parsed in my game.

For writing the JSFL - look for document called Extending Flash.

The rest was developed from scratch using Objective C with OpenGL. Do not see option of 'one-click' compilation or converting from Flash to iPhone (not considering CS5), but with developing extensions for Flash you could reuse some work.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard, but it is possible. I am working on a automatic code converter now.